# How to return an error message in JSON text when my simple REST get fails?

Tags: java, jquery, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I'm building a web app with Bootstrap, jQuery, and Spring MVC.

I have a web service defined that looks like this and it works fine ... the User object is returned in JSON format.

However, when there is an error, I'd like to return something that looks like this ...

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "Unable to retrieve user for id '55'; Could not connect to database."
}
```

... so I can parse out the error message and display it in a nice alert.

I tried throwing an Exception, but that didn't work.  What else should I try?  Here is the code ...

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

/* ... */

    @RequestMapping(value = "/json/user/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public User getUser(@PathVariable("userId") int userId) throws Exception {
        boolean bSuccess = false;
        String errorMsg = "";

        User user = null;
        try {
            user = userService.getUser(userId);
            bSuccess = true
        } catch (Exception x) {
            bSuccess = false;
            errorMsg = "Unable to retrieve user for id '"+userId+"'; "+x.getMessage();
        }

        // Need something here; 
        // if (!bSuccess) {
        //    return json error message ??
        // }

        return user;
    }

/* ... */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use spring to do that:

like this:

`````
@RestController
public class UserController {

/* ... */

    @RequestMapping(value = "/json/user/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView getUser(@PathVariable("userId") int userId) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(new MappingJackson2JsonView());

        User user = null;
        try {
            user = userService.getUser(userId);
            modelAndView.addObject("data", user);
            modelAndView.addObject("msg", "Inser yout msg");
            modelAndView.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (Exception x) {

            modelAndView.addObject("error", x);
            modelAndView.addObject("msg", ""Unable to retrieve user for id 
                         '"+userId+"'; "+x.getMessage();");
            modelAndView.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

        }


        return modelAndView ;
    }

/* ... */

}
````


I believe that this way is better. So you can standardize the responses using the ModelEndView. Look in <https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html>
`````

Answer (score 0):

ExceptionHandler will be help in this case.

Exception.java

```
public class Exception {

    private boolean success;
    private String message;
//....
}
```

ExceptionHandler.java

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {

        Exception ex = new Exception();
        ex.setSuccess(false);
        ex.setMessage("Unable to retrieve user for id....");
        return new ResponseEntity(ex,HttpStatus.NOK);
    }
}
```

So, whenever any exception occurs, it will come to this method.

Hope it helps!!